# Setting conditional shading in a cell using a color name from another cell

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet with data being populated from an external source.  There are columns which need conditional shading applied to them.  I have columns in the data which tell me what color each column should be shaded.  For example - I could have a column named "Species" who's conditional shading would be based on on a column named "Species color".  "Specie" would hold values such as "Maple", "Oak", etc. and "Species color" would hold values such as "yellow", "light steel blue", "green" (uses standard color names).

*Is there a way to get the cell shading indicated in the "Specie color" column to apply to the "Specie" column?*

I know that I can write some VBA using the "Value_Changed" event to pull this off, but I'd prefer to not have a bunch of "Value_Changed" calls going on with the amount of editing this file will demand.

Comment: Yes. How many colors are we talking? You'll need a rule for each color.

Comment: That's what I was trying to get away from.  The "Species color" values can be added to at any time, so I was hoping to find way to use one rule for all colors by passing in the name of the color to the formatting for the rule.  So when "Species color" = "Orange", the "Species" fill color gets set to Orange without having to add rule for each color.  I know that I can set the fill using a macro, but I'd prefer to do it using Conditional Formatting so that I'm not having to handle the OnChange event with every edit. If it can't be done, then I can write the VBA to handle it.

Comment: You'd have to write the VBA then. The format of a rule isn't dynamic like you want.